# Trouble understanding SQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(1) foo9, 
IF(foo1 = 0,
    IF(foo2 = 1,
        IF(foo3 = 0,
            IF(foo4 = 0,
                IF(foo5 = 0,
                    @prev:= COALESCE(CAST(@prev AS UNSIGNED),REPLACE(foo6, '-', '')),
                @prev:= NULL),
            @prev:= NULL),
        @prev:= NULL),
    @prev:= NULL),
@prev:= NULL) as foo8 
FROM (SELECT @prev:= NULL) f,
(SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE foo6 LIKE 'blah' ORDER BY REPLACE(foo6, '-', '') ) as foo7 
GROUP BY foo8 
HAVING foo8 > 0 AND foo9 >= ?
```

Having trouble with this SQL query, I understand the start with all the IF statements checking for if the previous line failed to meet all the criteria but where I am getting lost is on 
`FROM (SELECT @prev:= NULL) f, (SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE foo6 LIKE 'blah' ORDER BY REPLACE(foo6, '-', '') ) as foo7`

with `FROM (SELECT @prev:= NULL) f,` what is the `f` in this, and is it selecting all values that have the variable `prev` equal to `NULL` or is it simply setting `prev` to `NULL` here? Also the `ORDER BY REPLACE(foo6, '-', '') ) as foo7` as `foo7` isn't shown in the output, only `foo8` and `foo9`.

The query is looking through a list of numbers, checking them based on a set of parameters, and creating a list of sequential ranges, if the input were: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13` the output would

```
foo8 | foo9
  1  |  5
  8  |  2
  11 |  1
  13 |  1
```

Can someone please break this down for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is very product specific.)

Comment: It's MySQL running through HeidiSQL

Comment: I can't imagine a circumstance where this query would produce anything at all. Can you add sample data as text to the question please.